# How do i remove the numbers for the pager in the jquery cycle plugin

Tags: jquery, css, xhtml, cycle

I am trying to remove the numbers from the pager generated when using the jquery cycle plugin. The numbers only seem to show up in IE but I still need to remove them. The code I have is:

```
<div class="feature_span" style="background-color:#000000; background-image: url(images/banner-one.jpg); background-position:top center; background-repeat:repeat-x;" ></div>
<div class="feature_span" style="background-color:#000000; background-image: url(images/banner-two.jpg); background-position:top center; background-repeat:repeat-x;" ></div>
<div class="feature_span" style="background-color:#000000; background-image: url(images/banner-one.jpg); background-position:top center; background-repeat:repeat-x;" ></div>
<div class="feature_span" style="background-color:#000000; background-image: url(images/banner-two.jpg); background-position:top center; background-repeat:repeat-x;" ></div>

</div><!--End Homepage Slider-->

<div class="feature_nav"></div>
```

and

```
<script>
     // start slideshow 
    $('#homepage_slider').cycle({ 
        timeout:  7000, 
      //  before:   onBefore ,
        next:   '.feature_next',
        prev:   '.feature_prev',
        pager:  '.feature_nav'
    });
</script>
```

I'm sure there is a simple way of doing this that I'm missing. Could someone please help?

Comment: Your question is very hard to understand. If you expect a proper response, it would be helpful to clarify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some documentation is available here: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/pager2.html

```
$('#homepage_slider').cycle({ 
    timeout:  7000, 
  //  before:   onBefore ,
    next:   '.feature_next',
    prev:   '.feature_prev',
    pager:  '.feature_nav',
    pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) { 
        return foo;  //Where foo is whatever contents you want in each pager anchor.
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want pager, then delete this from your code. <strike>`pager:  '.feature_nav'`</strike>

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code, which works fine.

**HTML**

```
<div id="slider" class="pics">
        <img src="images/beach1.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
        <img src="images/beach2.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
        <img src="images/beach3.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
        <img src="images/beach4.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
        <img src="images/beach5.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
        <img src="images/beach6.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
        <img src="images/beach7.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
        <img src="images/beach8.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
    </div>
<ol class="pager"></ol>
```

**JS**

```
$('#slider').cycle({
                 fx: 'fade', 
         pager:  '.pager',     
            // callback fn that creates a thumbnail to use as pager anchor 
            pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) { 
                            return '<a href="#"></a>'; //what you want ti return like '<li></li>'
            }

    });
```

**Output: you can see**

```
<ol class="pager">
  <a href="#" class=""></a>
  <a href="#" class="activeSlide"></a>
</ol>
```

as a output of pager, can add css styles for pager class.